# NSViewController & Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsviewcontroller

I have a simple project which consists of a simple window with one view coming from a NSViewController (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAn6L.png )

[image]

The view is managed (+ linked, see screenshot) to my custom view controller object.

I dragged a ViewController Object into my MainMenu.xib, connected the view outlet and set the Controller-Class + Nib-Name.

When I launch the app my custom view won't show up in the window ("awakeFromNib" gets called in my custom NSViewController subclass!).

See Screenshot for IB details -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAn6L.png

Any ideas what I'm missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm presuming you have a separate Nib named `CustomImageView` that is not pictured (the one created automatically by Xcode). In that case you would add your controls and drawing code to the view in that separate Nib. To actually add that view controller's view to the window, you'll have to do it programmatically by making an IBOutlet connection from your AppDelegate to the view controller, and adding the following code when you want to add the view: (typically in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`)

```
[viewController.view setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)];
[viewController.view setFrame:NSInsetRect([window.contentView bounds], 20, 20)];
[window.contentView addSubview:viewController.view];
```

That will place it inset and centered like you have in the screenshot. The problem is that by creating the `view` connection in your MainMenu Nib you are overriding the connection in the separate, `CustomImageView` Nib. You can delete the Custom View object in your window... you'll have to add you custom view programmatically. It would be nice if it worked that way, but it doesn't.

EDIT:

It's because of the order that the nibs are unarchived. First CustomImageView is instantiated and all its connections are made. At this point the `view` property is correctly set. Then MainMenu hooks up the `view` property again, overriding the `view` property in the separate Nib. Now the view property is incorrectly set. That's normal behavior. If you're using separate nib you have to leave that unconnected and add the view controller's view in code.

An alternative would be to not use a separate Nib. Just delete it from your project, set up your view-in-window and leave your connection as-is. Now you can have a separate view controller managing it, without having to add any code. You really only want a separate Nib if the view is very complex, or if you want to load it lazily as needed, like if the user could select different views for the main window.

Comment: Thanks Francis! Any more info on why the CustomImageViewController.m view property (to the view in CustomImageViewController.nib) connection gets overridden by the connection in the MainMenu.nib?

Comment: I've added some explanation to my answer. You may not want to use a separate Nib in this case, unless your application is more complex than it appears. You should be able to design everything in MainMenu.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my previous answer because I thought you were developing for iOS devices. Now I realize that it a standard Mac OS project. But anyways, what I said about the setting the initial viewcontroller stays the same. Ok, you have a custom NSViewController object which has an NSView object.That's pretty good untill here. But, How should the app know what view to show when it launches. You should either make the initial view the NSViewController's view or the initial viewcontroller the NSViewController object itself so that it know what to show at start.I'd like to see you project if it's that simple.Just send it to my email.

Comment: hi Mikayil here is a link to the sample project the NSViewController Subclass is from an Apple example and the SPAppDelegate.m/.h is basically the vanilla XCode Template. I've just modified the MainMenu.xib. The Link: http://www.mediafire.com/?fodletn93e1ykub

Comment: Dear @bustaa, I'm very sorry for uploading the edited code so late but I've just been so busy that I couldn't spare time. Although I've no doubt that you've already fixed the problem just for the sake of little courtesy here's the link to the fixed project:mediafire.com/?f10km6w8ww9eo9r I just added some code to the applicationDidFinishLaunching method